# Adding to double Arraylist in HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to add pairs that add up to a certain number in java and one of the ways I am trying to attempt this is to create a double ArrayList within my HashMap. If I add 1 and 2 to my list, I will get 3 as my key. For example:

> ```
>     HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
>     ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
>     list.add(1);
>     list.add(2);
>     map.put(list.get(0) + list.get(1), new ArrayList<>(list));
> ```

Output looks like this

> ```
>    Key: 3 Value: [[1,2]]
> ```

If I were to add one more pair

> ```
>   Key: 3 Value: [[1,2],[0,3]]
> ```

but I keep getting a 'method is not applicable in the type HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<ArrayList>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, new ArrayList<>(list))'

I've also tried

> ```
>     new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(list))
> ```

thinking that I might need to initialize the bigger matrix first but I end up with the same error sadly.

Comment: It would be helpful for everyone (including those who will look to your question for help) if you show the map before and after values are added.  Add some values, show map.  Add some more, show map again.

Comment: Good idea! I just added some outputs since I have not seen a StackOverflow post quite similar to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```java
new ArrayList<>(list)
```

creates a flat `ArrayList<Integer>`, while the `HashMap` is expecting `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. By the same token, `new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(list))` also creates a flat Integer list because you are just doing the same thing twice. See the [API document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for `ArrayList`

This is one way that would work given the 2-D list setup:

```java
HashMap<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
List<List<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
outer.add(list);
map.put(list.get(0) + list.get(1), outer);
```

Comment: What would be the difference between the two? Will ArrayList<ArrayList> list look like this [[1,2][2,3]]? What would new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(list)) do? Or is that the wrong syntax?

Comment: Yes `List<List<Integer>>` looks like [[1,2,3], [1,2]]. As for `new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(list))`, since `list` is a 1-D list like [1,2,3], `new ArrayList<>(list)` also returns a 1-D list like[1,2,3]. Therefore `new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(list))` still returns a 1-D list like [1,2,3]. The syntax compiles, it just doesn't do what you thought it would do.

Comment: The api doc in the link in the answer specifies that when a `Collection` is passed into `ArrayList`'s constructor, it "Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection", not a **list of list** that contains the elements of the specified collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create some lambdas which may facilitate this.  For example.

```
Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Create a function to sum the elements of a list.

```
Function<List<Integer>, Integer> sum =
        list -> list.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Then create a `BiConsumer` to take the list pair and existing map and add them if need be.  The `computeIfAbsent`, enters a value for the key if the key was null or absent. The list is returned so the the pair can be added to the newly created list.

```
BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Map<Integer,
           List<List<Integer>>>> addToMap =
        (pair, map) -> {
            map.computeIfAbsent(sum.apply(pair),
                    v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(pair);
        };
```

Putting it all together.

```
addToMap.accept(List.of(1,2), map1);
addToMap.accept(List.of(0,4), map1);
addToMap.accept(List.of(1,5), map1);
addToMap.accept(List.of(0,3), map1);
addToMap.accept(List.of(-1,5), map1);
addToMap.accept(List.of(-1,2,3),map1);

map1.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
3=[[1, 2], [0, 3]]
4=[[0, 4], [-1, 5], [-1, 2, 3]]
6=[[1, 5]]
```

As you can see, this doesn't enforce any size limitations on the "pairs."

This may be overkill for what you want but there may be some elements you can put to use.  Also note that `List.of` above is immutable.